# Magento 2 : Save date and MultiSelect field value added in Ui_Component

Tags: uicomponent, custom-field, magento2.2.3

I've been facing issue with saving date field value.

I've added custom date field in sales_rule form , Field is added but can't able to save its value to DB.

Previously i added text field and its working fine but I am having issues for **date** and **MultiSelect** input.

> Vendor/Module/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_rule_form.xml

```
<field name="end_date" formElement="date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sales_rule</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <validation>
                <rule name="validate-date" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">End Date</label>
            <visible>true</visible>
            <dataScope>end_date</dataScope>
        </settings>
    </field>

    <field name="brand_ids" formElement="multiselect">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sales_rule</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <validation>
                <rule name="validate-brands" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
            <dataType>number</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Brand List</label>
            <dataScope>brand_ids</dataScope>
        </settings>
         <formElements>
        <multiselect>
            <settings>
                <options class="Vivek\ShopAsGroup\Block\SalesRule\BrandList"/>
            </settings>
        </multiselect>
</formElements>
    </field>
```

[image: DB]

What is missing ? Any suggestion would be really helpful to me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: use dataSource tag in your file or not.

Comment: No, I didn't use that. Can you please give me an example.

Comment: Are you using magento 2.2.3 ?

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd., Yes

Comment: In which table you want to save these two fields value in salesrule table or in your own table ?

Comment: In Sales Rule table, I've same field in DB with same name in Ui_Component file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to modifying **Marius** answer, He made me close to my issue.

I tried below code and it helps me to resolve my issue.

I used event `adminhtml_controller_salesrule_prepare_save`.

```
    $data = $observer->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    //print_r($data); exit;
    $request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();

    $brands = implode(',',$data['brands']);

    $startDate = $this->timeZoneInterface->date($data['start_date'])->format('Y-m-d'); 
    $endDate = $this->timeZoneInterface->date($data['end_date'])->format('Y-m-d');


    $request->setPostValue('brands',$brands);
    $request->setPostValue('start_date',$startDate);
    $request->setPostValue('end_date',$endDate);
```

Now Value has been saved to **DB** without any exception OR Notice.

Hope it will help others.

Answer (score 5):

This is completely untested but here goes.
As I can see for the other date type fields, the value needs some processing before saving it into the db: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/SalesRule/Controller/Adminhtml/Promo/Quote/Save.php#L30

Maybe you need to do the same for your date fields as well.
You can use this event `adminhtml_controller_salesrule_prepare_save` that receives as parameter the instance of the request, so you can get the post data and modify it.

As for multiselects, their selected values are sent as an array and you need to convert it to a string before saving it in the db.
You can use the same  event as above to do that.

something like:

```
$request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
$brandIds = $request->getParam('brand_ids');
$brandIds = implode(',', $brandIds);
$request->setParam('brand_ids', $brandIds);
```

If this works, it should solve the other issue you have: [Magento 2 : Notice Error - Array to String conversion](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/221049/magento-2-notice-error-array-to-string-conversion)

Comment: I tried but it's not working. If you have any other solution than you can tell me. Same exception with above `Array to string conversion`.

Comment: no other ideas. It worked like this for me but in a custom module where I had control over the controller. Here you don't have access to directly modify the controller.

Comment: Above mentioned link reflect 404 error and correct link was https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/SalesRule/Controller/Adminhtml/Promo/Quote/Save.php#

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and modify as per your requirements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sales_rule_form.sales_rule_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Main title</item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="delete" class="Vivek\ShopAsGroup\Block\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote\Edit\DeleteButton"/>
            <button name="save_and_continue" class="Vivek\ShopAsGroup\Block\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote\Edit\SaveAndContinueButton"/>
            <button name="reset" class="Vivek\ShopAsGroup\Block\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote\Edit\ResetButton"/>
            <button name="save" class="Vivek\ShopAsGroup\Block\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote\Edit\SaveButton"/>
            <button name="back">
                <url path="*/*/"/>
                <class>back</class>
                <label translate="true">Back</label>
            </button>
        </buttons>
        <namespace>sales_rule_form</namespace>
        <dataScope>data</dataScope>
        <deps>
            <dep>sales_rule_form.sales_rule_form_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="sales_rule_form_data_source">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <submitUrl path="sales_rule/promo_quote/save"/>
        </settings>
        <dataProvider class="Vivek\ShopAsGroup\Model\Rule\DataProvider" name="sales_rule_form_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>rule_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
        <fieldset name="rule_information" sortOrder="10">
        <settings>
            <collapsible>true</collapsible>
            <opened>true</opened>
            <label translate="true">Tab title</label>
        </settings>
        <field name="name" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sales_rule</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Rule Name</label>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <dataScope>name</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I think you not use datasource thats why you can not save date.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: So, you mean i need to override Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Dataprovider Class ? To save date and multiselct fields value ?!

Comment: No. get reference from here. it is helpful for you.

Comment: Use this code and modify as per your requirements. i hope its work for you.

Comment: I don't understand, What you exactly mean, I've add datasource tag to my existing xml but nothing happens, I checked vendor code dataprovider classis just load all data from form.

Comment: In this code `<submitUrl path="sales_rule/promo_quote/save"/>` this is use for to save your form data. You use this ?

Comment: But I've also added 2 more fields to this form with input type text both are saving to DB without rewrite any vendor class. Than why date and multiselect isn't working ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75477/discussion-between-dhaduk-mitesh-and-lazy-coder).